# Updating property of specific collection item with FindAndModify

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Post class:

```
public class Post
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public string CreatorName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get { return ObjectId.Parse(Id).CreationTime; } }
    public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment class:

```
public class Comment
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public string CreatorName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get { return ObjectId.Parse(Id).CreationTime; } }
    public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to find set the `DeletionDate` property of a `Comment` inside a `Post.Comments` given that `Comment.Id` and `Comment.CreatorId` equals the given parameters.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following:

```
var query = Query<Post>.ElemMatch(p => p.Comments, builder => 
    builder.And(
        Query<Comment>.EQ(c => c.Id, commentId),
        Query<Comment>.EQ(c => c.CreatorId, creatorId)));

var update = Update.Set("Comments.$.DeletionDate", DateTime.UtcNow);

var args = new FindAndModifyArgs
{
    Query = query,
    Update = update
};

var result = _db.Posts.FindAndModify(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
QueryDocument query= new QueryDocument();
            query.Add(new BsonDocument("Comments.$.Id","givenCommentId"));
            UpdateDocument update = new UpdateDocument();
            update.Add(new BsonElement("Comments.$.DeletionDate", "yourUpdatedDate"));
```

You can use it in FindAndModifyArgs

However I have forgotten whehther positional operator `$` can be used for two or more fields,so I dont add `new BsonDocument("Comments.$.CreatorId","givenCommentCreatorId")` in query.You need to test it.

Comment: This didn't work as it is, however thank you for mentioning the positional operator, that was needed in my update command. I solved it with `"$elemMatch"`.